# Using XPathExpression concurrently

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to use XPathExpression concurrently, but getting "org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing."
Using ThreadLocal doesn't help, it fails even if new XPathExpression created for each call.
This Junit test reproduces issue:

```
package testxpath;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;

class ConcurrentXpathTest {

    private static final String XPATH = "//*[(local-name()='Node')]";
    private static final String XML = "<Node>Something</Node>";

    @Test
    void testConcurrentXpath() {
        IntStream.range(0, 10000)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(v -> parse());
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private void parse() {
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(XPATH);
        xPathExpression.evaluate(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML)), XPathConstants.NODESET);
    }
}
```

How this can be fixed? Maybe advice some alternative libs.

Stacktrace:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:271)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:291)
    at com.corelogic.clp.tel2.gateway.services.ConcurrentXpathTest.parse(ConcurrentXpathTest.java:43)
    at com.corelogic.clp.tel2.gateway.services.ConcurrentXpathTest.lambda$testConcurrentXpath$0(ConcurrentXpathTest.java:37)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.accept(ForEachOps.java:205)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing.

    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:294)
    at com.corelogic.clp.tel2.gateway.services.ConcurrentXpathTest.parse(ConcurrentXpathTest.java:43)
    at com.corelogic.clp.tel2.gateway.services.ConcurrentXpathTest.lambda$testConcurrentXpath$0(ConcurrentXpathTest.java:37)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.accept(ForEachOps.java:205)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:271)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:291)
    ... 12 more
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:189)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEach(IntPipeline.java:404)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:560)
    at com.corelogic.clp.tel2.gateway.services.ConcurrentXpathTest.testConcurrentXpath(ConcurrentXpathTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:294)
    at com.corelogic.clp.tel2.gateway.services.ConcurrentXpathTest.parse(ConcurrentXpathTest.java:43)
    at com.corelogic.clp.tel2.gateway.services.ConcurrentXpathTest.lambda$testConcurrentXpath$0(ConcurrentXpathTest.java:37)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.accept(ForEachOps.java:205)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:271)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:291)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Does that stack trace really belong to this code? Where does `com.corelogic.clp.tel2.gateway.services.xml.HttpStatusService.getResponseStatus()` come into it?

Comment: Sorry, that was stacktrace from actual code. Edited post, now stacktrace is from test

Comment: Why don't you parse once and evaluate concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in some Xerces versions, even those that come with JDK/JRE.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8047329). Supposedly it is fixed in the default implementation that ships with Java 9+, but you might be out of luck with 1.8.

It might be worth checking which Xerces implementation you are using.

We stumbled onto the same thing with Xerces that is bundled with Apache Xalan 2.7.1. The object returned by `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` appears to contain internal state that is not thread safe, yet is shared between instances (or it produces other objects that exhibit the same). That appears to be the root cause of the exception.

Comment: No, the bug report you've linked is not fixed. They closed the ticket without any resolutions, as they cannot reproduce the error mentioned. Thus, Java 9+ will still have this issue. (I'm on Java 17 LTS, and we're still seeing this issue right now.)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce it easily with the JDK 11 and Xerces 2.12.0

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:276) ~[?:?]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339) ~[?:?]
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:122) ~[?:?]
```

To resolve this, I simply synchronize my builder:

```
Document xmlDocument = null;
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
synchronized(builder) {
  xmlDocument = builder.parse(stream);
}
```